Proof verification for $\det A$ changes sign if the rows of $A$ is interchanged.
While reading through Rudin's PMA Ch9 (Functions of Several Variables) p241~243 (determinant), Theorem 9.34 simply states that

(c) If $[A]_1$ is obtained from $[A]$ by interchanging two columns, then $\det [A]_1 = - \det [A]$.


Proof for (c): $\det [A]_1 = - \det [A]$ is an immediate consequence of the fact that $s(j_1, \, \cdots, j_n)$ changes sign if any two of the $j$'s are interchanged.

I found this fact nontrivial and attempted a proof below (see Lemma 7.3).
It would be greatly appreciated for any feedbacks.
I was also wondering if there is any other simpler proofs for this.
The relevant definitions are given in the image.


Here are some hints.
First consider swapping two adjacent indices. Suppose $\sigma$ is a permutation and choose some index $k$. Let $\sigma'$ be the permutation from swapping index $k$ and $k+1$. That is, if $\sigma=(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)$ then $\sigma'=(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_{k+1}, \sigma_k,...,\sigma_n)$ (with boundary cases as appropriate. Let $I = \{ (i,j) | i <  j \}$ and $I_- = I \setminus \{ (k,k+1)\}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
s(\sigma') &=& \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma'_{k+1}-\sigma'_{k})\prod_{(i,j) \in I'} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma'_j-\sigma'_i) \\
&=& \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma_{k}-\sigma_{k+1})\prod_{(i,j) \in I'} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma'_j-\sigma'_i) \\
&=& \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma_{k}-\sigma_{k+1})\prod_{(i,j) \in I'} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma_j-\sigma_i) \\
&=& -\operatorname{sgn} (\sigma_{k+1}-\sigma_{k})\prod_{(i,j) \in I'} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma_j-\sigma_i) \\
&=& - s(\sigma)
\end{eqnarray}
Now suppose we want to swap two indices $a<b$. Note that it takes $b-a-1$ pairwise swaps to bring $a$ beside $b$ as in:
\begin{eqnarray}
* \ ... * \ a \ * \ &...& * \ b \ * \ ... *\\
* \ ... * \ * \ a \ &...& * \ b \ * \ ... *\\
&\vdots &\\
* \ ... * \ * \ * \,&...& \ a \ b \ * \ ... *\\
\end{eqnarray}
and another $b-a$ swaps to move $b$ back in the same fashion. That is $2(b-a)-1$ swaps, and so $s( \sigma') = - s(\sigma)$, where $\sigma'$ is the permutation that swaps indices $a,b$.

An alternate proof of this would use the fact that the determinant is multilinear and $0$ when two columns are equal. Consider an $n\times n$ matrix $A=[\mathbf{x}_{1},...,\mathbf{x}_{n}]$, where the $\mathbf{x}_{k}$ are $n\times 1$ column vectors. Consider $D=\det[\mathbf{x}_{1},...,\mathbf{x}_{i-1},\mathbf{x}_{i}+\mathbf{x}_{j},...,\mathbf{x}_{j-1},\mathbf{x}_{i}+\mathbf{x}_{j},...,\mathbf{x}_{n}]$. By the fact that the determinant is $0$ when two columns are equal, we get that $D=0$. But you can also compute $D$ using multilinearity and the fact that the determinant is $0$ when two columns are equal, to get that $$D=\det(A)+\det(B),$$ where $B=[\mathbf{x}_{1},...,\mathbf{x}_{i-1},\mathbf{x}_{j},...,\mathbf{x}_{j-1},\mathbf{x}_{i},...,\mathbf{x}_{n}]$. Now, using the fact that $D=0$ you get the desired result.

The purpose is to prove that this is true for $\det$, so that would be a little circular.

@copper.hat You can show the multi linear property and the two column equal implies zero property without using this fact.
